Why Bella believe sleeping with another man improved her relationship with Duncan?
After sleeping with another man, Bella, a childlike young woman,
speaks to Duncan Wedderburn, a debauched lawyer:

Duncan: You fu_ked for money?
Bella: And as an experiment. And it is good for our relationship as it
gladdens my heart toward you.

Why does Bella believe that sleeping with another man will improve her relationship with Duncan?

You answered the question immediately before asking it in the sentence you bolded.

My recollection is that, by comparing sex with Duncan with what the customers of the brothel usually did, she had become aware of the fact that he was putting an effort towards giving her a pleasant sexual experience. If you recall, she started the job under the delusion that it would be pleasant and that it would sate her sexual appetite.
In that sense it "gladdens her heart towards him". Of course, her being unaware of social conventions and of the intricacies of the human nature, she overestimates the positive effect that her having a higher opinion of him might have on a relationship that was already strained beyond repair. Moreover, she was not factoring in the role of Duncan's personal issues in him becoming more and more conflictual overtime.
